# IntelliJ IDEA - несколько систем контроля версий

Tags: intellij-idea, контроль-версий

Необходимо, чтобы проект был под управлением двух систем контроля версий (VCS) - *Mercurial* и *Git*. Если подключать их в *IntelliJ IDEA* поодиночке, то всё работает. Но если подключить сразу две к одному и тому же каталогу, то работает только одна (как я понял, та, что указана последней).

Лазить в настройки и каждый раз переключать лениво и задалбывает. Можно ли как-то заставить *IntelliJ IDEA* нормально работать одновременно с несколькими VCS на один каталог?

P.S. Версия *IntelliJ IDEA* - 15.0.4.

Comment: я лично бы выбрал одну базовую систему, а вторую использовал через "переходник". Например, такой - http://hg-git.github.io/

без подобных переходников в системе будет такое кол-во багов...

Comment: сомневаюсь, очень уж странный юзкейс.